# Why is the Star of the County Down referred to as Colleen?

Tags: song-lyrics, cultural-context, oral-tradition

While listening to [the Irish Rovers version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jXLnSkGmTdQ) of the traditional Irish song "Star of the County Down", I noticed an apparent discrepancy in her name:

> Near Banbridge town, in the County Down
> One morning in last July
> Down a boreen green came a sweet Colleen
> And she smiled as she passed me by.
>
> [...]
>
> As she onward sped, sure I scratched me head
> And I looked with a feeling rare.
> And I said, says I, to a passerby
> "Who's the maid with the nut brown hair?"
>
> Well, he looked at me, and he said to me,
> "That's the gem of Ireland's crown.
> Young Rosie McCann from the banks of the Bann
> She's the star of the County Down."

If her name is Rosie McCann, then why does he keep calling her Colleen (including in the chorus of the song)? For that matter, why does he call her Colleen before even knowing who she is, as he needs to ask a passerby? Was Colleen in Ireland just a "placeholder" name, to be used for someone if you don't know their actual name, like Jimmy in Glasgow or Charlie in Ghana?

Comment: Like Sheila in Australia?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Colleen is the Anglicised version of the Irish Gaelic *cailín*, meaning *young woman* or *maid*.

Derivation: *caile* (“maid”) +‎ -*ín* (diminutive suffix)

Although girls are sometimes *named* Colleen, in the context of the lyric it shouldn't have a capital C.

The [New English-Irish dictionary](https://www.teanglann.ie/en/fgb/cail%C3%ADn) has other usages.

Comment: Great find. This also fits with [boreen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boreen), another Anglicised Gaelic word in the same line. And looking online for the lyrics of this song, I see that "colleen" is often not capitalised even though it was in the Youtube video linked in the OP.

Comment: @Rand al'Thor Yes, and potcheen from poitín. I hadn't realised how popular Colleen was as a name in the US. Maybe that's why it got capitalized on YouTube. Wikipedia's 'Colleen' entry lists many famous women but there's not a Brit in sight,  though I've certainly heard the name here.

Comment: For a modern usage of _cailín_ to mean young woman, see [Maith an cailín, Malala](https://www.irishtimes.com/opinion/letters/maith-an-cail%C3%ADn-malala-1.1503674), where 'Maith an cailín' may be translated as 'well done, young woman'

Comment: IMO 'Colleen' is a misprint, and what is meant is 'cailín'  An accepted version of the lyrics is given [here](https://www.metrolyrics.com/star-of-the-county-down-lyrics-the-high-kings.html). To use 'colleen' (no capital C) also irks: the song is 'borrowing' the word 'cailín' from  _[Gaeilge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irish_language)_ (note the _[fada](https://www.bitesize.irish/blog/our-fada/)_ on the final 'i'), at one time spoken throughout Ireland, and still taught at school in Ireland

Answer (score 2):

From the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colleen) for Colleen:

> Colleen is a common English language name of Irish-American origin and **a generic term for Irish women or girls**, from the Irish cailín 'unmarried girl/woman', the diminutive of caile 'woman, countrywoman'.
>
> (My emphasis)